# jQuery - Keeping an asynchronous function from running more than once simultaneously

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I have an asynchronous function that is triggered by an "onmouseover" that sends a request for children nodes to a list and displays them. Setting it to be synchronous prevents this, but as far as I know, it needs to be asynchronous in order to display a loading icon in Chrome and IE. The problem is that if you mouseover more than once while the function is still executing, it loads the children multiple times. What I am having trouble with is preventing the function from running more than once at a time, to prevent the children nodes from being loaded more than once.

Thanks in advance!

My ajax call (jQuery instead of $ because I am running in noconflict mode):

```
 var ul = "#ul_" + categoryId;
    var ifUlExists = jQuery(ul); 

    // Only if UL not already loaded
    if (ifUlExists.length == 0) {

        jQuery.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/adminajax/add_kids',
     data: { 
      categoryId: categoryId
     },
     beforeSend:function(){
      // Toggle +/- icon  
      jQuery(expandIcon).addClass("loading");
     },
     success:function(resp){
      var kids = resp;         
      // If there are kids returned by the query
      if (kids){
       var container = "#c_"+categoryId;       
         jQuery(kids).insertAfter(jQuery(container));
         jQuery(ul).slideDown("slow");
      }
     })};
    } else {
  jQuery(expandIcon).addClass("collapse");
  jQuery(ul).slideDown("slow");  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to run "simultaneously"; a better word would be "concurrently".  Anyway just set a flag:

```
if (ifUlExists.length === 0 && !$('body').data('loadingUl')) {
  $('body').data('loadingUl', true);
  // the rest of your code
}
```

Using the "body" element data is just one of a zillion ways to do it, but I kind-of like it because `$('body')` is made pretty cheap by jQuery.  You could keep the flag anywhere of course.

Comment: Thank you SO much!!! Absolutely what I've been spending hours upon hours trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

A flag is one option:

```
var running = false;

$(selector).mouseover(function() {
    if(!running) {
         running = true;
         callAsyncFunction();
    }
});
```

and in the callback of the Ajax request, set `running = false` again.

If you want to do that for several elements, you can use the [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function of that element as [@Pointy describes in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484116/jquery-keeping-an-asynchronous-function-from-running-more-than-once-simultaneou/4484148#4484148).